# Apache CXF spring bean is not injected

Tags: java, spring, cxf, apache-tomee

I have developed SOAP based web service using Apache CXF 3 and Spring 3 and deployed on Tomee. I have 2 xml ( 1. beans.xml(cxf service) 2. spring-servlt.xml). I am referring some DAO layer beans in my cxf service xml. it is not being injected. when I did analyze on CXFServlet class. loadBus method getting application context from WebApplicationContextUtils class.

**it was working fine in Jetty. but it is not working in Tomeeif. if I load cxf bean using ContextLoaderListener, web services were not exposed. after that I used config-location. for jetty I didn't used separate xml for cxf. I merged cxf beans in my application bean, it was loaded by dispatcher servlet and was working good**

**CXFServlet.java**

```
protected void loadBus(ServletConfig sc) {
    ApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.
        getWebApplicationContext(sc.getServletContext());

private ApplicationContext createSpringContext(ApplicationContext ctx,
                                                   ServletConfig servletConfig,
                                                   String location) {
        XmlWebApplicationContext ctx2 = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        createdContext = ctx2;

        ctx2.setServletConfig(servletConfig);
        Resource r = ctx2.getResource(location);
        try {
            InputStream in = r.getInputStream();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //ignore
            r = ctx2.getResource("classpath:" + location);
            try {
                r.getInputStream().close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                //ignore
                r = null;
            }
        }
        try {
            if (r != null) {
                location = r.getURL().toExternalForm();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //ignore
        }        
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx2.setParent(ctx);
            String names[] = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(Bus.class);
            if (names == null || names.length == 0) {
                ctx2.setConfigLocations(new String[] {"classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml",
                                                      location});                
            } else {
                ctx2.setConfigLocations(new String[] {location});                                
            }
        } else {
            ctx2.setConfigLocations(new String[] {"classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml",
                                                  location});
            createdContext = ctx2;
        }
        ctx2.refresh();
        return ctx2;
    }
```

if (ctx != null) {
       ctx2.setParent(ctx);

**since ctx (wac)is null cxf is not able to set parent context.** bean inject is not working. please guide me why this wac is null.

**Web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/connector/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config-location</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>    
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I  tried all most all options have  already been provided in form. 
Do I need to add any parameter in Tomee or on my code.

Comment: have you add ContextLoaderListener to web.xml

Comment: if I load cxf bean using ContextLoaderListener, web services were not exposed. after that I used config-location. it was working fine in Jetty. but it is not working in Tomee.

Answer (score 0):

TomEE is a full stack Java EE server. If you're deploying a Spring based application, **you likely don't** need to enable CDI with beans.xml.

If you're **absolutely positive** you need both CDI and Spring enabled, I suggested you do two things to resolve the issue: One use a debugger to figure out if the bean that isn't getting injected is a Spring or CDI bean. Second, turn on verbose Spring logging to see what's it's injecting there.

Good luck!